# spring mvc display base64 as image

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) `WYSWIG` as my text editor on my site.
When User paste an image on the editor it is sent in post as `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANsd..." />`

I would like to get this `base64` string, save it in database and then create endpoint like `/image/{id}` which will show this image so in post I would not have to put whole `base64` string in image source but just url like shown above.

this is how I save the `base64` as `byte[]`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/main/createpost"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postPost(Model model, Principal principal,@RequestParam(name="editor-content") String postPayload) throws IOException {


        postPayload = checkAndSavePhotos(postPayload);
        model.addAttribute("editor",postPayload);
        return "createpost";
    }
```

`checkAndSavePhotos` is checking if editor contains any images and if so it stores it in database:

```
private String checkAndSavePhotos(String postPayload) throws IOException {
        int i =1;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*<img src=\".*;base64,(.*?)\".*/>");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(postPayload);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            PostPhoto postPhoto = new PostPhoto();
            byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(matcher.group(i).getBytes());
            MultipartFile mf =null;
            try {
                BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", baos);
                baos.flush();
                mf = new MockMultipartFile("test", baos.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            postPhoto.setContent(mf.getBytes());
            postPhoto = postPhotoService.save(postPhoto);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I have made it this way because on my other form with `<input type='file' />` when I was using `FileBucket` it was enough for me to show `fileBucket.getFile().getBytes();` in order to show image. I was trying to create `MultipartFile` from `byte[]` and made it the same way.

My Endpoint to show image:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main/postphoto/{imageId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable Long imageId) throws IOException  {
        PostPhoto image = postPhotoService.findById(imageId);

        return image.getContent();
    }
```

Now when I am looking at database `content` column looks like:
`\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d49484452000000280000002808060000008cfeb86d0000033f4944415478daed9(...)`

while file from `filebucket`
`\377\330\377\341\000\030Exif\000\000II*\000\010\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\377\354\000\021Ducky\000\001\000\004\000\000\000A\000\000\377\341\003ohttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/\000<?xpacket begin="\357\273\277" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> (...)`

Can anyone give me a hint how to made it works?

Comment: You can write your file in the response as described here http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-sample-application-for-downloading-files or return HttpEntity as describe here http://memorynotfound.com/spring-mvc-download-file-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a stupid mistake.

My database column `content` was type of `text` so I was storing `byte[]` as a text, so it's not wierd that the file was not decoded correctly by browser.

Changing database column type to `bytea` solved problem.